# java copy string of characters between two special characters with split

Tags: java, android

```
   String Code = "[123456]Ahmed"
 String[] code_after_Cut = code.split("\\]" , "\\[");
```

I need to cut "123456" from Code String

Comment: You better use regex with a capturing group. Please research that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it in two steps. by the way you had a capital c in code

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    String code = "[123456]Ahmed";
    System.out.println("code : " + code.split("\\]")[0].split("\\[")[1]);

    //or with regex it can goes like this
    Pattern patern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{6})");
    Matcher matcher = patern.matcher(code);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("code: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
 }
```

Comment: You welcome. You can accept the solution if it fits your needs then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// as @RealSkeptic says... Regular expressions might be your point...
import java.until.regex.*;

....

String code = "[123456]Ahmed";
Pattern P = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+?\\)]Ahmed");
Matcher m = P.matcher(code);
String numberStr = null;
if (m.find()) numberStr = m.group(1);
// should print: 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that its always the name "Ahmed" so I would recommend this:

```
    val full = "[123456]Achmed"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([0-9]*)\\].*")
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(full)
    if (matcher.matches())
        Log.d("TAG", matcher.group(1))
```